# activating threads C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, activation

i have this code in C#:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(functionsActivations(3, 4000, 0, 4));
Thread t2 = new Thread(functionsActivations(3, 4000, 5, 9));
t1.start();
t2.Start();
Thread t3 = new Thread(functionsActivations(4, 4000, 0, 4));
Thread t4 = new Thread(functionsActivations(4, 4000, 5, 9));
```

It is not working. How can I tell it to call the method I gave it?
Secondly, I want t3 and t4 to be activated after t1 and t2 finish running. How can I do that?
Third, I want t1 and t2 to not block (so that t2 wouldn't have to wait until t1 finishes). Is what I did correct?

Comment: Yea mate, 2/11 Accepted is not good. Go through those questions and mark the ones that answered your situation as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"It is not working" isn't a very clear set of symptoms. What are you observing?

EDIT: Okay, now that you've said what the compiler error is, it's much easier to diagnose. You're currently calling a method and trying to use the result as a task for the thread to execute. Assuming you *actually* want to make that method call when the thread is started, you want something like this:

C# 2:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(delegate() { functionsActivations(3, 4000, 0, 4); });
```

C# 3:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => functionsActivations(3, 4000, 0, 4));
```

An altnerative to having lambda expressions all over the place would be to write a utility method:

```
private static Action DeferFunctionActivations(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return () => functionsActivations(a, b, d, d);
}
```

Then you could use:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(DeferFunctionActivations(3, 4000, 0, 4));
```

etc.

For the rest of the post I'll assume C# 3.

Additionally, `t1.start()` should be `t1.Start()` - C# is case sensitive.

To answer your final point, `t1` and `t2` are currently independent - they won't be blocking each other unless you've got synchronization somewhere in the code that they're running.

If you only want `t3` and `t4` to start when `t1` and `t2` have finished, you could use `Thread.Join`:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => functionsActivations(3, 4000, 0, 4));
Thread t2 = new Thread(() => functionsActivations(3, 4000, 5, 9));
t1.Start();
t2.Start();
t1.Join();
t2.Join();
Thread t3 = new Thread(() => functionsActivations(4, 4000, 0, 4));
Thread t4 = new Thread(() => functionsActivations(4, 4000, 5, 9));
t3.Start();
t4.Start();
```

Note that that means that *this* thread will wait until `t1` and `t2` have finished, too. If that's not good enough for you, there are various options but basically you'll want something else to asynchronously wait for t1 and t2 to complete. For example, you *could* tie up an extra thread to do that:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => functionsActivations(3, 4000, 0, 4));
Thread t2 = new Thread(() => functionsActivations(3, 4000, 5, 9));
t1.Start();
t2.Start();
Thread t3 = new Thread(() => functionsActivations(4, 4000, 0, 4));
Thread t4 = new Thread(() => functionsActivations(4, 4000, 5, 9));
Thread t5 = new Thread(() =>
{
    t1.Join();
    t2.Join();
    t3.Start();
    t4.Start();
});
t5.Start();
```

Somewhat icky, but it should work.

Are you able to use .NET 4.0? If so, the Parallel Extensions framework makes a lot of this significantly easier.

Comment: thanks! you solved me the last two questions, but not the first.
it's not working from other reason, the problem is in the function i gave the thread in th ctor. it tells me that he can't convert from void to system.threading.threadstart...

Comment: Why are you passing a constructor to a thread?  What are you trying to do?  Create an object in a thread because construction takes a long time?

Comment: no, thid code is in the ctor, i pass regular funcgtions to the thread

Comment: delegate function will be the better option